# Trying to understand the math behind the perspective matrix in WebGL

Tags: math, matrix, opengl-es, webgl, perspectivecamera

All matrix libraries for WebGL have some sort of `perspective` function that you call to get the perspective matrix for the scene.
For example, the `perspective` method within the [`mat4.js` file that's part of `gl-matrix`](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/gl-matrix/mat4.js) is coded as such:

```
mat4.perspective = function (out, fovy, aspect, near, far) {
    var f = 1.0 / Math.tan(fovy / 2),
        nf = 1 / (near - far);
    out[0] = f / aspect;
    out[1] = 0;
    out[2] = 0;
    out[3] = 0;
    out[4] = 0;
    out[5] = f;
    out[6] = 0;
    out[7] = 0;
    out[8] = 0;
    out[9] = 0;
    out[10] = (far + near) * nf;
    out[11] = -1;
    out[12] = 0;
    out[13] = 0;
    out[14] = (2 * far * near) * nf;
    out[15] = 0;
    return out;
};
```

I'm really trying to understand what all the math in this method is actually doing, but I'm tripping up on several points.

For starters, if we have a canvas as follows with an aspect ratio of 4:3, then the `aspect` parameter of the method would in fact be `4 / 3`, correct?

[image: 4:3 aspect ratio]

I've also noticed that 45° seems like a common field of view. If that's the case, then the `fovy` parameter would be `π / 4` radians, correct?

With all that said, what is the `f` variable in the method short for and what is the purpose of it?
I was trying to envision the actual scenario, and I imagined something like the following:

[image: Side view of [perspective in 3D scene]

Thinking like this, I can understand why you divide `fovy` by `2` and also why you take the tangent of that ratio, but why is the inverse of that stored in `f`? Again, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what `f` really represents.

Next, I get the concept of `near` and `far` being the clipping points along the z-axis, so that's fine, but if I use the numbers in the picture above (i.e., `π / 4`, `4 / 3`, `10` and `100`) and plug them into the `perspective` method, then I end up with a matrix like the following:

[image]

Where `f` is equal to:

[image]

So I'm left with the following questions:

1. What is `f`?
2. What does the value assigned to `out[10]` (i.e., `110 / -90`) represent?
3. What does the `-1` assigned to `out[11]` do?
4. What does the value assigned to `out[14]` (i.e., `2000 / -90`) represent?

Lastly, I should note that I have already read [Gregg Tavares's explanation on the perspective matrix](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-perspective/), but after all of that, I'm left with the same confusion.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) helps a bit. This is referencing outdating fixed-function GL a tiny bit, but the math is still valid.

Comment: Sorry, derhass, but that link was even more confusing than all the other links I've looked at thus far. I guess what I'm asking for more than a math explanation is a conceptual explanation of what's happening, and how the matrix is formed, given the actual scenario.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's see if I can explain this, or maybe after reading this you can come up with a better way to explain it.

The first thing to realize is WebGL requires clipspace coordinates. They go -1 <-> +1 in x, y, and z. So, a perspective matrix is basically designed to take the space inside the *frustum* and convert it to clipspace.

If you look at this diagram

[image: frustum-side]

we know that tangent = opposite (y) over adjacent(z) so if we know z we can compute y that would be sitting at the edge of the frustum for a given fovY.

```
tan(fovY / 2) = y / -z
```

multiply both sides by -z

```
y = tan(fovY / 2) * -z
```

if we define

```
f = 1 / tan(fovY / 2)
```

we get

```
y = -z / f
```

note we haven't done a conversion from cameraspace to clipspace. All we've done is compute y at the edge of the field of view for a given z in cameraspace. The edge of the field of view is also the edge of clipspace. Since clipspace is just +1 to -1 we can just divide a cameraspace y by `-z / f` to get clipspace.

Does that make sense? Look at the diagram again. Let's assume that the blue `z` was -5 and for some given field of view `y` came out to `+2.34`. We need to convert `+2.34` to +1 *clipspace*. The generic version of that is

clipY = cameraY * f / -z

Looking at `makePerspective'

```
function makePerspective(fieldOfViewInRadians, aspect, near, far) {
  var f = Math.tan(Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5 * fieldOfViewInRadians);
  var rangeInv = 1.0 / (near - far);

  return [
    f / aspect, 0, 0, 0,
    0, f, 0, 0,
    0, 0, (near + far) * rangeInv, -1,
    0, 0, near * far * rangeInv * 2, 0
  ];
};
```

we can see that `f` in this case

```
tan(Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5 * fovY)
```

which is actually the same as

```
1 / tan(fovY / 2)
```

Why is it written this way? I'm guessing because if you had the first style and tan came out to 0 you'd divide by 0 your program would crash where is if you do it the this way there's no division so no chance for a divide by zero.

Seeing that `-1` is in `matrix[11]` spot means when we're all done

```
matrix[5]  = tan(Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5 * fovY)
matrix[11] = -1

clipY = cameraY * matrix[5] / cameraZ * matrix[11]
```

For `clipX` we basically do the exact same calculation except scaled for the aspect ratio.

```
matrix[0]  = tan(Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5 * fovY) / aspect
matrix[11] = -1

clipX = cameraX * matrix[0] / cameraZ * matrix[11]
```

Finally we have to convert cameraZ in the -zNear <-> -zFar range to clipZ in the -1 <-> + 1 range.

The standard perspective matrix does this with as [reciprocal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) so that z values close the the camera get more resolution than z values far from the camera. That formula is

```
clipZ = something / cameraZ + constant
```

Let's use `s` for `something` and `c` for constant.

```
clipZ = s / cameraZ + c;
```

and solve for `s` and `c`. In our case we know

```
s / -zNear + c = -1
s / -zFar  + c =  1
```

So, move the `c' to the other side

```
s / -zNear = -1 - c
s / -zFar  =  1 - c
```

Multiply by -zXXX

```
s = (-1 - c) * -zNear
s = ( 1 - c) * -zFar
```

Those 2 things now equal each other so

```
(-1 - c) * -zNear = (1 - c) * -zFar
```

expand the quantities

```
(-zNear * -1) - (c * -zNear) = (1 * -zFar) - (c * -zFar)
```

simplify

```
zNear + c * zNear = -zFar + c * zFar
```

move `zNear` to the right

```
c * zNear = -zFar + c * zFar - zNear
```

move `c * zFar` to the left

```
c * zNear - c * zFar = -zFar - zNear
```

simplify

```
c * (zNear - zFar) = -(zFar + zNear)
```

divide by `(zNear - zFar)`

```
c = -(zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar)
```

solve for `s`

```
s = (1 - -((zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar))) * -zFar
```

simplify

```
s = (1 + ((zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar))) * -zFar
```

change the `1` to `(zNear - zFar)`

```
s = ((zNear - zFar + zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar)) * -zFar
```

simplify

```
s = ((2 * zNear) / (zNear - zFar)) * -zFar
```

simplify some more

```
s = (2 * zNear * zFar) / (zNear - zFar)
```

*dang I wish stackexchange supported math like their math site does :(*

so back to the top. Our forumla was

```
s / cameraZ + c
```

And we know `s` and `c` now.

```
clipZ = (2 * zNear * zFar) / (zNear - zFar) / -cameraZ -
        (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar)
```

let's move the -z outside

```
clipZ = ((2 * zNear * zFar) / zNear - ZFar) +
         (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar) * cameraZ) / -cameraZ
```

we can change `/ (zNear - zFar)` to `* 1 / (zNear - zFar)` so

```
rangeInv = 1 / (zNear - zFar)
clipZ = ((2 * zNear * zFar) * rangeInv) +
         (zFar + zNear) * rangeInv * cameraZ) / -cameraZ
```

Looking back at `makeFrustum` we see it's going to end up making

```
clipZ = (matrix[10] * cameraZ + matrix[14]) / (cameraZ * matrix[11])
```

Looking at the formula above that fits

```
rangeInv = 1 / (zNear - zFar)
matrix[10] = (zFar + zNear) * rangeInv
matrix[14] = 2 * zNear * zFar * rangeInv
matrix[11] = -1
clipZ = (matrix[10] * cameraZ + matrix[14]) / (cameraZ * matrix[11])
```

I hope that made sense. Note: Most of this is just my re-writing of [this article](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/).

Comment: I've been mulling over your answer almost nonstop since you posted it a couple of days ago, and finally, it's starting to come together, although I will admit that I am still a bit confused. I have also look very heavily at [your post](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-perspective/) as well as the explanations on the perspective matrix in...

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/WebGL-Programming-Guide-Interactive-Graphics/dp/0321902920/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1423125734&sr=8-1&keywords=WebGL) and [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Math-Primer-Graphics-Game-Development/dp/1568817231/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1423125771&sr=8-1&keywords=3D+Math) in an effort to better understand what's going on. With all that said, this is my understanding thus far, and please correct if I'm wrong:

Comment: `Math.tan(fovy / 2)` is essentially describing the relationship between `y` and `z`. (I mean, after all, that's just the basic trigonometric definition of the tangent.) As such, the inverse of that is equal to `maxZ / maxY`. As such, when you multiple the y part of a vertex by that, the division by `maxY` essentially has the effect of normalizing the y from 0 to 1. From there, the larger the Z, the larger the y value ultimately becomes. Also, I get why you do the same thing for x but also factor in the aspect ratio. That's fine. Now, where I'm still very confused is the z part. For one...

Comment: You wrote `zeroToOne = (someY - near) * rangeInv;` above, but I'm wondering if `someY` should in fact be `someZ`. Please let me know your opinion on that. Thank you. Also, I totally get how you calculated `clipspace` to go from `-1` to `1`. That's totally fine. However, I don't understand how that `clipspace` calculation maps to `out[10]` and `out[14]`. Specifically, what does `zNear + zFar` do in `out[10]` and what does `zNear * zFar` do in `out[14]`? Sorry for all the questions. Your post has been extremely helpful, but as you can see, I'm still a bit confused. Thank you.

Comment: added some more but I'm confused myself :p

Comment: This is slowly starting to click for me. Lemme mull over it a bit more, and I'll get back with you with a more complete reply. Thanks again, gman.

Comment: I re-wrote the entire thing based off an article found and linked to. See if it helps

Comment: That was excellent! Thank you so much. I also looked at the article you referenced at the end, and I think I'm set. I'll continue to look over this for the next couple of days to ensure that it sticks (as best it can), but I actually get it now, which is great. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand the line " if we define f = 1 / tan(fovY / 2)" why do we do that?

Comment: "so that z values close the the camera get more resolution than z values far from the camera." Can you expand a bit on this? I'm assuming you mean that objects closer to the camera appear bigger, right?

Comment: No, don't mean the objects closer to the camera appear bigger. I mean that (as an example but not actual math) close the camera the z-buffer might be able to distinguish between 2 things 1mm apart where as far from the camera it might only be able to distinguish between 2 things 1 meter apart or more. A better way to put is is close it can distinguish between thing fractions of a unit apart and far away only things multiple units apart. See this: https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized

Answer (score 0):

`f` is a factor which scales the y-axis, such that all points along the top plane of your viewing frustum, post-perspective-division, have a y-coordinate of 1, and those on the bottom plane have a y-coordinate of -1. Try plugging in points along one of those planes (examples: `0, 2.41, 1`, `2, 7.24, 3`) and you can see why this happens: because it ends up with the pre-division y equal to the homogeneous w.

Comment: Sneftel, thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "right plane" and "left plane"? Also, your answer sounds like `f` is merely normalizing everything in relation to the `y` value, but I don't get why and what that has to do with homogenous w. Also, could you please provide some insight into questions #2-#4 above? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "top or bottom" planes. Consider all the points in space which, when rendered, would be drawn as pixels on the extreme top or bottom of the screen. Those form flat surfaces in the world.

Comment: As for 2 and 4, just as `f` and `f/aspect` scale x and y into the (-1,1) range, those scale z into the (-1, 1) range. And 3 is to set up the perspective division. I think you might need to play around a bit more on paper to understand what's going on here. In particular, see if you can figure out why points with a large z coordinate are drawn closer together than points with a small z coordinate.