# Negative values for gl_Position.w?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Is the w component of gl_Position required to be greater than zero? Because when I set it to a negative number nothing is drawn but positive numbers are fine.

```
gl_Position = vec4(vPos,0,-1);
```

Face culling is not enabled btw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Has the `w` component of `gl_Position` required to be greater than zero?

No, but the result of `gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w` has to be in the range (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1), the normalized device space. This means each component (`x`, `y` and `z`) of the result,  has to be `>= -1.0` and `<= 1.0`.

[image]

But, **if the `w` component is negative, nothing is draw anyway**. Because `gl_Position` defines the clip space. The condition for a homogeneous coordinate to be in clip space is

```
-w <=  x, y, z  <= w.
```

If `w = -1` this would mean:

```
 1 <= x, y, z  <= -1.
```

and that can never be fulfilled.
(see [Why does GL divide `gl_Position` by W for you rather than letting you do it yourself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085117/why-does-gl-divide-gl-position-by-w-for-you-rather-than-letting-you-do-it-your))

**Explanation:**

The coordinates which are set to `gl_Position` are [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). If the `w` component of a [Homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) is 1, it is equal to the [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) built of the components `xyz`.

[Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) are used for the representation of the perspective projection.

In a rendering, each mesh of the scene usually is transformed by the model matrix, the view matrix and the projection matrix.

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. The projection matrix transforms from view space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) in the range (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates. 
 Every geometry which is out of the NDC is clipped.

At Orthographic Projection the coordinates in the eye space are linearly mapped to normalized device coordinates. (TCommonly the `w` component is 1.0)

[image]

At Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport. 
 The eye space coordinates in the camera frustum (a truncated pyramid) are mapped to a cube (the normalized device coordinates).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I still wonder why I get nothing on the screen when w is negative even with all the coordinates within [-1,1] range. Do you think it could be a driver problem or something? I use intel HD graphics with Haswell architecture if it helps

Comment: I see but they still remain inside [-1,1] after division. Would you do me a favor and test it on your own system please? Just draw a triangle with its w coordinates set to -1 and see if anything is shown.

Comment: @ You are right, if `w = -1` the vertex is clipped, see the adds to the answer

Comment: That's interesting. I never knew -w must be less than w